# get function and sub body

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to write something that will delete unused subs and functions in VBA. I'm at the starting point of trying to pull the sub and function body. I have some code that gives me the names of all subs and functions but i need the entire body
i don't understand how the code works so i can't adapt it

```
Sub sbGetListOfProcedures()

    Dim obj As AccessObject
    Dim dbs As Object
    Dim strMdl() As String
    Dim Idx As Integer
    Dim vrFormName As String

    Set dbs = Application.CurrentProject

    ReDim strMdl(0)

    For Each obj In dbs.AllModules
        strMdl(UBound(strMdl)) = obj.Name
        ReDim Preserve strMdl(UBound(strMdl) + 1)
    Next obj

    ReDim Preserve strMdl(UBound(strMdl) - 1)

    Dim strSQL As String
    sbWOff
    strSQL = "Delete * from ZProcedures;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    sbWOn
    Application.Echo False
    While Idx <= UBound(strMdl)
        fnFindProcedure (strMdl(Idx))
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Wend
    Application.Echo True
  
    For Each obj In dbs.AllForms
        vrFormName = obj.Name
        DoCmd.OpenForm vrFormName, acDesign, , , , acHidden
        If Forms(vrFormName).HasModule = True Then
            fnFindProcedure ("Form_" & vrFormName)
        End If
        DoCmd.Close acForm, vrFormName, acSaveNo
    Next obj
    
End Sub

Function fnFindProcedure(vrModuleName As String)

    Dim obj As AccessObject
    Dim dbs As Object

    Dim DAOdb As DAO.database
    Dim vrRs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim vrModule As Module
    Dim vrIdx As Long
    Dim vrJdx As Long
    Dim vrMyLine As String
    Dim vrProc As Integer
    Dim vrProcLn(5) As String

    vrProcLn(0) = "Private Sub"
    vrProcLn(1) = "Private Function"
    vrProcLn(2) = "Public Sub"
    vrProcLn(3) = "Public Function"
    vrProcLn(4) = "Sub"
    vrProcLn(5) = "Function"

    Set dbs = Application.CurrentProject
    Set DAOdb = CurrentDb
    Set vrRs1 = DAOdb.OpenRecordset("ZProcedures", dbOpenDynaset)

    vrIdx = 1
    DoCmd.OpenModule (vrModuleName)
    Set vrModule = Modules(vrModuleName)
    While vrIdx <= vrModule.CountOfLines
        vrMyLine = vrModule.Lines(vrIdx, 1)

        vrJdx = 0
        Do While vrJdx <= UBound(vrProcLn)
            vrProc = InStr(vrMyLine, vrProcLn(vrJdx))
            If (vrProc = 1) Then
                With vrRs1
                Debug.Print vrMyLine
                    .AddNew
                    !ModuleName = vrModuleName
                    !ProcedureCall = vrMyLine
                    ' !ProcedureTxt = vrModule
                    .Update
                End With
                Exit Do
            End If
            vrJdx = vrJdx + 1
        Loop

        vrIdx = vrIdx + 1
    Wend
    DoCmd.Close acModule, vrModuleName

End Function
```

Comment: Do you know [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) or [MZ-Tools](https://www.mztools.com/) - they both have features to show unused subs etc.

Comment: http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm